# How to return parent records, only if there is a child record, with a max date that falls between a date range?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I need to return all completed parent items from my PARENTS table, when they have been completed within a date range. All actions against a parent are stored in a child table, PARENT_ACTIONS.The difficulty I am having, is that there may be more actions after the completed action, or even multiple completed actions stored for that PARENT_ID and I only need the parent returned if the max action is a completed action, and it falls within a user selected date range.

I have tried searching the forums, but most of what I have found has been "how to find the max date of a child record for a parent record", which was helpful in how to do max, but not helpful to my exact problem.

I don't recall all that I have tried, but I am currently trying this code, which does return the correct results (11 rows), it just takes 10 minutes due to the terribly inefficient SQL.

```
var parents = (from p in db.PARENTs
               where p.PARENT_ACTION
                        .Any(pa => pa.ACTION_ID == 99 
                                && pa.ACTION_DATE >= beginDate
                                && pa.ACTION_DATE <= endDate
                                && pa.ACTION_DATE == p.PARENT_ACTION.Max(pam => pam.ACTION_DATE))
              select p);
```

I would like to be able to write something that translates very similar to the below SQL, which returns in < 1 second for 11 rows.

```
select * from parent p
 where p.STATUS = 99
   and exists (select 'x' from parent_action pa
                where pa.PARENT_ID = p.ID
                  and pa.ACTION_ID = 99
                  and pa.ACTION_DATE = (select max(pam.action_date)
                                          from parent_action pam
                                         where pam.parent_id = p.id)
                  and pa.action_date between to_date('04/10/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('04/23/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

*****Update 1*****

I am using System.Data.Entity to query an Oracle 12c database

```
Sample data:
STATUS
ID, DESC
1, ENTERED
2, SUBMITTED
99, COMPLETED

ACTIONS
ID, DESC
1, ENTER
2, SUBMIT
99, COMPLETE

PARENT
ID, STATUS
1, 99
2, 1
3, 99
4, 99

PARENT_ACTIONS
ID, PARENT_ID, ACTION_ID, ACTION_DATE
1, 1, 1, 04/01/2019
2, 1, 2, 04/05/2019
3, 1, 99, 04/11/2019
4, 2, 1, 04/11/2019
5, 3, 1, 04/15/2019
6, 3, 2, 04/16/2019
7, 3, 99, 04/17/2019
8, 3, 2, 04/18/2019 --Parent sent back to submitted status
9, 4, 1, 04/01/2019
10, 4, 2, 04/11/2019
11, 4, 99, 04/15/2019
12, 4, 99, 04/24/2019 --Completion details updated by customer, business rules require a new complete action be written
```

Based on this sample data, with a date range of 4/10/2019 through 4/23/2019, I want to write something that will ONLY return Parent ID 1 because this is the only parent with a max action date that is both 1) a COMPLETE action (99) and 2) between the specified date range. I want Parent 4 to be excluded, because the max action date falls outside of the specified date range.

***** Update 2 *****

It looks like I do have the correct code already to return the desired results; however, I thought I was doing something terribly wrong as the query execution exceeded 10 minutes. After further investigation, it appears that I am another victim of "CAST AS" appearing in the generated SQL, and drastically reducing performance. In my case, it is casting my ID columns in the SQL as number (10,0), when in my table the ID columns are Integer, and in my EF Model the ID columns are Int32. I'm not quite sure how to fix this or if I should just write my own SQL for this particular data need.

Comment: can you provide table schemas, sample data, and expected output?  also what dbms are you using (MSSQL, MySQL, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Edited:
Order the actions by date in a descending order, then taking the first (latest) action. This action's status has to be 99 and it's date should be in the required range:

```
    var prs = (from p in parents
           where p.PARENT_ACTION
                .OrderByDescending(pa => pa.ACTION_DATE)
               .Take(1)
               .Any(pa => 
                    pa.ACTION_ID == 99
                    && pa.ACTION_DATE >= beginDate
                    && pa.ACTION_DATE <= endDate)
          select p);
```

Edit (according to the following link, this code should be equivalent to T-SQL's ranking functions which should be more efficient: https://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/12/29/linq-how-to-get-the-latest-last-record-with-a-group-by-clause/)

```
    var parentIds = new HashSet<int>(from a in PARENT_ACTIONS
            group a by a.PARENT_ID into grp
            let maxDate = grp.Max (g => g.ACTION_DATE)
            from p in grp
            where p.ACTION_DATE == maxDate 
                && p.ACTION_ID == 99
                && p.ACTION_DATE >= beginDate
                && p.ACTION_DATE <= endDate
            select p.PARENT_ID);
    var prs = parents.Where(p => parentIds.Contains(p.PARENT_ID));
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply; however, that is not what I am asking for. I need to return a parent if the maximum action date is for a completed action, and that maximum action date falls between the date range. I am going to edit my question with some sample data, to hopefully clarify.

Comment: That does not return the desired results. I am getting 153 items, when I should be getting 9. In looking into the additional 144 items it returned, I see that these are old records with bad data - they have no actions in the actions table, but they are still included with this code. This query also takes over 10 minutes to complete. It is looking like the code I have in my question may be the correct code, it is just executing extremely poorly, and I've yet to be able to figure out why.

Comment: It seems both our codes suffer from the "select N+1 problem."
I found a post which may provide a better solution, see my edited answer.

Comment: That seems to work well for a small set of data, but if the date parameters are expanded, I end up with a HashSet with 25k items in it, that doesn't translate very well to a sql where clause using parendIds.Contains(). I don't think that it is suffering from the "select N+1 problem, as it is generating a single query that returns all of the information I need. It appears that my problem is that the SQL generated has a lot of CAST AS Number(10,0) in place of the Integer database columns. If I remove the CAST AS from the sql, it performs just as well as my written sql.

Comment: Are you sure it's not running faster because it's a second run and the DB cache comes into action? Its a bit strange how it can find the max for each parent in an efficient way without using grouping. Can you post the generated SQL?

Comment: I just modified the .edmx file in notepad to change the column mapping type to "int" from "number". Once I did this, the generated SQL no longer had all of the CAST functions, and executes quickly. It's frustrating that, with Database first model creation, I can't modify the column mappings in the UI, and that it mapped an Oracle Integer column to a number type.

Answer (score 0):

> I only need the parent returned if the max action is a completed action, and it falls within a user selected date range.

So you want the Parent, if the Status of the parent Completed (99) and the last ParentAction of this Parent was complete with a date between beginDate and endDate. Or more precise: the last ParentAction of this Parent has an ActionId Complete (99) and an ActionDate between beginDate and endDate.

Whenever you want an "Item with its sub-items", like a "School with its Students", a "Client with his Orders", a "Product with its ProductParts", consider using [Queryable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8)

```
var parentsThatCompletedTheirActionsInTime = dbContext.Parents
    .Where(parent => parent.Status == 99) // = completed
    .GroupJoin(dbContext.ParentActions,   // GroupJoin with the ParentActions
        parent => parent.Id,              // from every Parent take the primary key
    parentAction => parentAction.Id,      // from every ParentAction the foreign key

    // ResultSelector: take the parent and all its matching parentActions
    // to make one new object
    (parent, actionsOfThisParent) => new
    {
        Parent = parent,
        LastParentAction = actionsOfThisParent
           .Select(action => new
           {
               IsCompleted = action.ActionId == 99,
               ActionDate = action.ActionDate,
           })
           .OrderByDescending(action => action.ActionDate)               
           .FirstOrDefault(),
    })

    // Keep only those parents where the Last Action was completed in time
    .Where(joinResult => joinResult.LastParentAction.IsCompleted
        && joinResult.LastParentAction.ActionDate >= beginDate
        && joinResult.LastParentAction.ActionDate <= endDate)

    // finally: keep only the Parent:
    .Select(joinResult => joinResult.Parent);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This does seem to return the correct results, but it still is extremely slow (cancelled after 14 minutes, removed all of the CAST functions and returned in <1 second). I thought that there was an issue with my original code, and that I could get the data I need more efficiently; however, it appears that the problem is the way Linq to Entity is generating the SQL, specifically in regards to adding "CAST( .... AS NUMBER(10,0))" around any column in the select, or where clause that is an INTEGER column in Oracle, and an Int32 in my model.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, the code I originally had DOES return what I want, and it appears to be a relatively efficient way of doing so. My initial reason for asking this question was to see if 1) My code was correct to return what I was wanting, and more importantly 2) Was there a more efficient way of retrieving the data I wanted, since my code was taking 10+ minutes to return - I thought for sure I must have been doing something wrong.

After trying all of the wonderful code provided (Thank you very much Metheny and Harald) and still experiencing 10+ minute return times for 10 rows, I stumbled upon some posts suggesting that Linq to Entity can have terrible performance when the generated SQL contains "CAST( FIELD AS TYPE)", which turns out to be exactly what I was experiencing.

The following code returns the desired results for my question.

```
var parents = (from p in db.PARENTs
               where p.PARENT_ACTION
                        .Any(pa => pa.ACTION_ID == 99 
                                && pa.ACTION_DATE >= beginDate
                                && pa.ACTION_DATE <= endDate
                                && pa.ACTION_DATE == p.PARENT_ACTION.Max(pam => pam.ACTION_DATE))
              select p);
```

In addition to this code, to remove the "CAST AS" from the generated SQL, I had to modify my .edmx file in Notepad and change the type of all of the Oracle INTEGER columns from "number" to "int".

Finally, let me state that I'm not quite sure how to best handle closing my question. I'm not sure, because my original code in the question returns the correct results, Harald's code returns the correct results, and Metheny's code also returns the correct results (although I do have concerns if there are a high number of parent ids). It also appears that my initial question wasn't the question I needed to ask to fix my problem, I just wasn't aware at the time of what the real problem was.